# How does this log rule work?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms

In my textbook, I saw the following steps:

Step (1): $\ln|v(t)-49| = -\frac{t}{5}+C$

Step (2): $v(t) = 49 + ce^{-t/5}$

How did they go from step 1 to 2.
When solving this, I would think to put $v(t) = e^{-t/5+C} +49$.
Can someone explain how the c was brought to the front as a product?

Comment: The $\ln$ function is the inverse of the exponential function $\exp$.

Comment: If $C$ is a constant, then $e^{C}$ is also a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\ln|v(t)-49| = -\frac{t}{5}+C$$

By definition of logarithm:

$$ v(t)-49= e ^{-\dfrac{t}{5}+C} =e ^{-\dfrac{t}{5}} e ^C= e ^{-\dfrac{t}{5}} c, $$

because any function of an arbitrary constant ( capital C) is another arbitrary constant (small c).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that this is coming from an indefinite integral and/or a differential equation, and that $C$ is the constant of integration, then you can use the rules of exponentiation to write $v(t) = e^{-\frac{t}{5}+C} + 49 = e^{-\frac{t}{5}}e^C + 49 = ce^{-\frac{t}{5}} + 49$, where $c = e^C$. Notice that since $C$ is an arbitrary constant, $e^C$ is likewise arbitrary, so we can replace it with an equivalent expression and it doesn't change the set of solutions.